# How to combine/join observables that arrive at different speeds in RxJava 2?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to combine Observables that are produced at different speeds.

Consider a stream of price quotes that are pushed from an external service, they can arrive (sometimes) at a high rate. After receiving each quote other services calculate indicators based on this price and emit these indicators.

I now want to combine these Observables of prices and indicators and deliver them to another service. Every price has a timestamp and every indicator has the timestamp of the price that was used for its calculation. The prices and the indicators should be grouped by this timestamp.

In the following Code I try to illustrate this. I am using Observable.combineLatest() because this seems suitable, but as you can see in `combineLatestToFast()` this approach will not work if a new price arrives before all indicators are calculated. It will work however if the new price arrives after each indicator is 'calculated', as you can see in `combineLatestToFast()`.

It seems like I am missing something. I've tried different approaches using windowing, buffering and Flowables, but it seems I am not getting my head around this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
package rx;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.observables.ConnectableObservable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class RxCombineObservablesReproducer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RxCombineObservablesReproducer reproducer = new RxCombineObservablesReproducer();
        //this will work as indented
        reproducer.combineLatestExample();
        //this not
        reproducer.combineLatestToFast();
    }

    private void combineLatestExample() {

        ConnectableObservable<Data> priceObs = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(i -> new Data("price", i * 1.00, Instant.now())).publish();
        Observable<Data> indicator1Obs = priceObs.map(i -> new Data("indicator1", i.getValue() * 2.00, i.getTs())).delay(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Observable<Data> indicator2Obs = priceObs.map(i -> new Data("indicator2", i.getValue() / 2.0, i.getTs())).delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Disposable dis = Observable.combineLatest(priceObs, indicator1Obs, indicator2Obs, (Data price, Data indicator1, Data indicator2) -> {
                    if (checkSameTs(price, indicator1, indicator2)) {
                        Map result = new HashMap<String, Data>();
                        result.put("price", price);
                        result.put("indicator1", indicator1);
                        result.put("indicator2", indicator2);
                        return result;
                    }
                    return new HashMap<String, Data>();
                }

        )
                .filter(m -> !m.isEmpty())
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        priceObs.connect();
        sleep(1000);
        dis.dispose();
    }

    private void combineLatestToFast() {

        ConnectableObservable<Data> priceObsToFast = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(i -> new Data("price", i * 1.00, Instant.now())).publish();
        Observable<Data> indicator1ObsToFast = priceObsToFast.map(i -> new Data("indicator1ToFast", i.getValue() * 2.00, i.getTs())).delay(9, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Observable<Data> indicator2ObsToFast = priceObsToFast.map(i -> new Data("indicator2ToFast", i.getValue() / 2.00, i.getTs())).delay(15, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        System.out.println("\n------------------------------toFast------------------------------\n");
        Disposable dis = Observable.combineLatest(priceObsToFast, indicator1ObsToFast, indicator2ObsToFast, (Data priceToFast, Data indicator1ToFast, Data indicator2ToFast) -> {
                    //System.out.println("combineToFast");
                    if (checkSameTs(priceToFast, indicator1ToFast, indicator2ToFast)) {
                        Map result = new HashMap<String, Data>();
                        result.put("priceToFast", priceToFast);
                        result.put("indicator1ToFast", indicator1ToFast);
                        result.put("indicator2ToFast", indicator2ToFast);
                        return result;
                    }
                    return new HashMap<String, Data>();
                }

        )
                .filter(m -> !m.isEmpty())
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
        priceObsToFast.connect();
        sleep(500);
        dis.dispose();
        System.out.println("The End");
    }

    private boolean checkSameTs(Data... dataObjects) {
        Instant ts = dataObjects[0].getTs();
        boolean same = true;
        for (Data data : dataObjects) {
            if (!data.getTs().equals(ts)) {
                same = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return same;
    }

    private void sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Data {
        private String name;
        private Double value;
        private Instant ts;

        Data(String name, Double value, Instant ts) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
            this.ts = ts;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        Double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        Instant getTs() {
            return ts;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{" +
                    "ts=" + ts +
                    ",name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    '}';
        }
    }


}
```

---

**Output**

```
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.061978200Z,name='price', value=0.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.061978200Z,name='indicator1', value=0.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.061978200Z,name='indicator2', value=0.0}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.156025200Z,name='price', value=1.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.156025200Z,name='indicator1', value=2.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.156025200Z,name='indicator2', value=0.5}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.256024800Z,name='price', value=2.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.256024800Z,name='indicator1', value=4.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.256024800Z,name='indicator2', value=1.0}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.356112300Z,name='price', value=3.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.356112300Z,name='indicator1', value=6.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.356112300Z,name='indicator2', value=1.5}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.456075700Z,name='price', value=4.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.456075700Z,name='indicator1', value=8.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.456075700Z,name='indicator2', value=2.0}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.557074500Z,name='price', value=5.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.557074500Z,name='indicator1', value=10.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.557074500Z,name='indicator2', value=2.5}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.656075600Z,name='price', value=6.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.656075600Z,name='indicator1', value=12.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.656075600Z,name='indicator2', value=3.0}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.755255800Z,name='price', value=7.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.755255800Z,name='indicator1', value=14.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.755255800Z,name='indicator2', value=3.5}}
{price=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.856452700Z,name='price', value=8.0}, indicator1=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.856452700Z,name='indicator1', value=16.0}, indicator2=Data{ts=2018-06-15T13:06:57.856452700Z,name='indicator2', value=4.0}}

------------------------------toFast------------------------------

The End
```

**EDIT:**

I've added a marble diagram in response to the first answer. The Problem is not to calculate the indicators based on the price. Like described above, this already happened by external services, but to group the corresponding prices and indicators together based on a key (in this case the timestamp) regardless when and in which order they arrive, and then send them to the following services.

Please follow the link to see the diagram, I am not allowed to embed the image.

[Marble diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1dO1.png)

Comment: This sounds like a typical dependent calculation, which is `flatMap`: `prices.flatMap(price -> calculateBasedOn(price).map(calc -> combine(price, calc)))`. See [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows).

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not helpful. My Problem is not the calculation of the indicators, this happened already in an external service, but the combination/grouping of the price, indicator one and indicator two. I will add a marble diagramm to the original post to point this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the marble diagram, since sequences are not in the same order, `combineLatest` simply won't work. You have to keep hashmaps for each flow and signal to a common consumer step to see if it can establish a row of values from those hashmaps.

```java
ConcurrentHashMap<Key, A> mapA = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ConcurrentHashMap<Key, B> mapB = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
ConcurrentHashMap<Key, C> mapC = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Observable<A> sourceA = ...
Observable<B> sourceB = ...
Observable<C> sourceC = ...

Observable.merge(
    sourceA.map(v -> { mapA.put(v.getKey(), v); return v.getKey(); }),
    sourceB.map(v -> { mapB.put(v.getKey(), v); return v.getKey(); }),
    sourceC.map(v -> { mapC.put(v.getKey(), v); return v.getKey(); }),
)
.flatMap(key -> {
    if (mapA.containsKey(key) && mapB.containsKey(key)
            && mapC.containsKey(key)) {
        return Observable.just(new Result(
            mapA.remove(key), mapB.remove(key), mapC.remove(key)
        ));
    }
    return Observable.empty();
})

.subscribe(result -> { /* do something with a row */ });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input David. I was hoping that I missed some secret Rx sauce. I thought that maybe it is bad style to keep a state on my own. Your answer is actually quite close to the solution I came up with. At least now I am sure, that this is the right way. I am still learning to think reactive.